# Spring MVC + Hibernate + Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've been going round in circles for a while trying to figure why I am receiving the below error.

I'm in the process of creating a 'bootstrap' Spring MVC project utilising Spring security and Thymeleaf for the view layer.

With regards to integrating security, I'm heavily relying on source from :

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

The main difference with the mkyong.com project is that i've omitted the following class from the setup (under the impression that it isn't needed) : SpringMvcInitializer

The source for the my new app under development is here :

https://github.com/robinsm/springmvc-security-hibernate-thymeleaf

If I do not include that class SpringMvcInitializer, I get the following error upon startup relating to wiring org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService

```
2015-07-30 16:29:41.759:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-0: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2575f671{/,file:/Volumes/MacPartition/Dropbox/dev/sites-spring/Creative74SpringMvcHibernateBootstrapWithSecurity/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/Volumes/MacPartition/Dropbox/dev/sites-spring/Creative74SpringMvcHibernateBootstrapWithSecurity/src/main/webapp/}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.configuration.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=userDetailsService)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
```

If not relating to something entirely different, why should I include the SpringMvcInitializer and what does it do?

Any insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those that tried to help on this one and at least pointed me in the right direction.

Ultimately, the problem was down to Spring MVC being initialized twice.  Originally, the app was initialized using :

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

When I integrated the Spring security, this initializer was being executed along with the new initialiser :

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.configuration.AppConfig;
import uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.configuration.HibernateConfiguration;
import uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.configuration.WebMvcConfig;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class, HibernateConfiguration.class, WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

The following article covering the evolution of Spring initialisation helped me determine the double initialisation and to work out the corrections needed.

http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/01/understanding-spring-web-initialization.html

Removing the class AppInitializer and making some amends to the SpringMvcInitializer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.configuration.SecurityConfig.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

You're asking it to `@Autowire` a `UserDetailsService` but you don't give it a definition of that bean. You must supply a class that implements `UserDetailsService`.

**Edit** Ah, after your comment I see that class now. I believe the issue is your `ComponentScan` syntax, instead of this:

```
@ComponentScan({"uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.*"})
```

Try this

```
@ComponentScan({"uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate"})
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the comment but I do have a class implementing UserDetailsService which is named MyUserDetailsService in the uk.co.creative74.springmvchibernate.service package.  I don't know the application cannot find it ...

Comment: Hi Chris, I've tried that also (with other combinations) and it's still the same result.  I'm assuming it something along those lines though ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `SpringMvcInitializer` *is* needed because it registers the Spring servlet and bootstraps configuration. Pay attention to this snippet:

```java
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
}
```

This tells Spring to load configuration according `AppConfig` class, which contains the `@ComponentScan` which will find the `userDetailsService`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I can't try this until I return to the office but I have a question in the meantime.  In the previous iteration this project before integrating Spring security, the inialisation of spring using a class implementing AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer wasn't needed.  Hibernate was setup without issues and configuration classes were picked up via annotation.  So why does the introduction of Spring security require this additional initialisation?